# Get vmId via pyVmomi

Tags: python, vmware, vmware-tools, pyvmomi

Currently Im using `vim-cmd` to perform multiple operations in my VMware center.

I'm using SSH paramiko module to connect and retrieve `vim-cmd` command status:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.getstate 13
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on 13
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off 13
vim-cmd vmsvc/destroy 13
```

I want to use `pyVmomi` library to run some commands and for this it is required to provide the `vmId` identifier:

```
from pyvim import connect
from pyVmomi import vim
from pyVmomi import vmodl

vim-cmd vmsvc/get.summary 13
Listsummary:

(vim.vm.Summary) {
   dynamicType = <unset>, 
   vm = 'vim.VirtualMachine:13',
```

What command can I use to get the `vmId`?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for here..

Comment: I'm referring to the vmid in ESXi CLI obtained using vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are calling the vmid is called a ManagedObjectReference or mor, or a moref (within the context of the vSphere Web services API). With pyVmomi there are a couple of ways to get the moref. One is to just print the object. That method will print the moref in a format such that it gives the ManagedObjectType:moref like below. Another way if you just want the actual moref you can access vm._moId. Below is an example using a Datacenter object.

```
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect
from pyVmomi import vim
si = SmartConnect(host='10.12.254.137', user='administrator@vsphere.local', pwd='password')
content = si.RetrieveContent()
children = content.rootFolder.childEntity
for child in children:
    print child

'vim.Datacenter:datacenter-33'
'vim.Datacenter:datacenter-2'
children[0].name
'1000110'
dc = vim.Datacenter('datacenter-33')
dc._stub = si._stub
dc.name
'1000110'
```

If you want to access an Object using its moref then follow the example I provided. I covered this on my blog [here](http://www.errr-online.com/index.php/2014/10/12/using-the-managed-object-id-to-create-objects-with-pyvmomi/) about a year or so ago. You might check out that article for a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same thing,
 
I know it has been a while but I suggest this
 
hack which works fine for me, I hope you can use it.

```
buf = ("%s" % (vm.summary.vm))
```

which for example gives

```
vim.VirtualMachine:11
```

now, we wish to extract the number and for python3 it is recommended using regular expression.

```
import re #regular expression
re.findall('\d+', buf)
```

which result with a list with 1 element

'11'
 
`type(buf)<br/>`
 
`<class 'list'>`

Comment: This answer is formatted oddly. Can you fix the formatting so it is clear what would be in the config and what is context and  comments?

Comment: Thanks, I have modified it.